# Extracting objects from table

Tags: r, vector, extract

I've worked with table(vector) to see what  the frequency is of each element from my vector. But now I want to use the frequency of a number. I've tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
table(vector)[2]
```

Then I get for example

```
7
2
```

So the number 7 attend 2 times in the vector. But I want to work with the "2", how do I do that?

Silke

Answer (score 2):

```
tt <- table(vector)
```

To get the frequency of "7" (column name here) , you can do this:

```
tt[["7"]]
```

You can also transform your table to a data.frame:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(tt)
dat[dat$Var1==7]$Freq
```

Comment: And I've I don't know the number 7, so for example that I want to see what the frequency is in the second column, what do I have to do then?

Comment: @Silke it is just a named vector. So you index it as a normal vector , So  `tt[[2]]` to get the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have the following

```
vector <- sample(c(5:10),100,replace=T)
> table(vector)
vector
 5  6  7  8  9 10 
22 17 20 14 10 17
```

The first row is just the names and the bottom row is the values so if you do

```
x <- table(vector)
str(x)
 'table' int [1:6(1d)] 22 17 20 14 10 17
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ vector: chr [1:6] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
```

you get the actual frequency values itself in a vector with names. Why are you not able to work with this? Can you give an example of the problem you are facing.

Comment: In my work, I don't know very much about my vector, I don't know what the names are, don't know what the length is,... After some procedures, I become a vector and now I want to work with these frequency's en their names